# Determining Blanking for HDMI Transmitter

Tags: driver, video, hdmi

I am working on a project which produces a video output over an HDMI connector. The driver I am using is the [Texas Instruments TFP410PAP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tfp410.pdf).

The image I am attempting to display is WVGA, 800 x 480 pixels. I designed my board to configure the driver via the I2C bus which is controlled by a small MSP430 microcontroller. The I2C registers allow me to enable and configure a built-in data-enable (DE) signal in the driver IC which controls the blanking at the top, bottom, left, and right of the screen. There are six registers that control this: DE_DLY (left border width), DE_CNT (image width), H_RES (screen width), DE_TOP (top border height), DE_LIN (image height), and V_RES (screen height). DE_CNT and DE_LIN are easy - that would be the 800 x 480 pixels of the desired image. However, the issue has to do with determining the other values. When a monitor is plugged in to my board, the driver chip does not know what its resolution is, so selecting values for DE_DLY, H_RES, DE_TOP, and V_RES seems tricky.

I know that some monitors will automatically detect the input resolution and adjust their settings accordingly, but in any case how would I determine appropriate values for the four aforementioned configuration registers? Obviously my goal would be to center the displayed image in the screen and make it as large as possible (i.e. minimize blanking time), but I am not sure if there is a limit to that (in other words, is there a minimum required blanking time?). Furthermore, if the monitor has a different aspect ratio than the input signal (which is likely), how will it handle the transmitted WVGA image?

Below is a graphic from page 16 of the datasheet to illustrate the purpose of the different values:

[image]

Comment: That is a bit tricky indeed - 800 x 480 seems to be an odd resolution, it is not seen in VESA DMT or CTA resolution standards. What device is generating the video that is sent to this TI chip? TI chip does not need to generate DE from HS and VS internally if the original video has HS VS and DE. Oh and this is a DVI transmitter chip - if the protocol is not HDMI you are not officially allowed to use HDMI connector for it. But the identification of display should be easy via DDC, just read the EDID and you know what the monitor supports (it may not list 800x480 formats though).

Comment: This board provides the ability to connect an external monitor to an oscilloscope. The original oscilloscope has an 8.5" 800x480 WVGA screen. Originally I didn't see a DE signal, so I designed my board to use an internally-generated blanking signal. It wasn't until after I ordered the boards that I realized a DE signal did exist, it just used a different name and it didn't register to me that it was the same. In order to avoid having to rework the boards, I am hoping I can configure the internal DE generator to operate in its stead.

Comment: As for the second half of your comment, I am going to need further clarification. The datasheet states on Page 1 under section 2 Applications that this is a DVI/HDMI transmitter (HDMI video only), so it is HDMI-capable. That being said, I realize in order to actually call it HDMI there are a number of certifications I would need to acquire, and that's a bridge I'll cross when I come to it. Regarding reading the EDID over DDC, that's definitely something I'll need to look into. That would be a benefit of using an internally-generated DE signal - I could configure a custom resolution.

Comment: This chip is only a DVI protocol transmitter. There is no way this chip can be switched to HDMI protocol. It is not HDMI capable. I don't see why they would mention HDMI at all. Also, you can't configure custom resolutions - The resolution is what comes into this chip, and that's 800x480 of active video with the blanking and pixel clock it happens to have. What is the pixel clock frequency by the way?

Comment: Sorry, that was poor phrasing on my part. Not resolution, but rather positioning of the 800x480 image on the screen. As for HDMI, it is mentioned in several places so you can see why I am a bit confused here.

Comment: Additionally, the BeagleBone uses this chip (the TFP410) to drive its HDMI connector.

Comment: DE already tells the monitor where the 800x480 active video data window is so there is nothing to change. It might be difficult to get standard monitors to accept this custom resolution. Indeed, BeagleBone has TFP410 with HDMI connector to provide a DVI-D output - maybe because it is a smaller connector. They never claim it is HDMI output. As there are so many things now, if you like, create a chat to continue.

Comment: I have created a chat room, though I will be AFK for the next several hours. Chat can be found here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98960/determining-blanking-for-hdmi-transmitter

Answer (score 2):

After some extremely helpful discussion in chat with Justme, I believe I have found the solution.

I began by probing points around the VGA reference board, which I am converting to HDMI (or at least DVI-D, I'll need to look into this per the comments on the original post). I measured Vsync, Hsync, and the pixel clock. I also managed to solder a very fine wire on the blank pin of the original VGA driver chip (which, like an idiot, I overlooked in my design) and was able to measure the blanking interval. I came up with the following:

- Vsync = 60.125 Hz
- Hsync = 37.879 kHz
- Pxclk = 40 MHz
- Blank = 6.4 us
- EN = 20 us

I also decided to simply plug in the reference board to a monitor and view the monitor's settings after it auto-configured. I'm not sure why I didn't do this from the beginning. The monitor showed a resolution of 800 x 600 px rather than the 800 x 480 that I thought, which was only the native resolution of the device (not the external monitor resolution). I found [this webpage](http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/800x600@60Hz) showing the timing of an 800p x 600p x 60 Hz VGA signal which was consistent with my measurements:

[image]

Now that we had determined the correct resolution and timings, I was able to determine the correct register values. Just a reminder, these were the registers for which I needed numbers:

- DE_CNT - display width (in pixels)
- DE_LIN - display height (in pixels)
- DE_DLY - horizontal sync pulse + back porch (in pixel clocks)
- DE_TOP - vertical sync pulse + back porch (in pixel clocks)

Using the table of timings on the tinyvga website, I was able to determine the following:

- **DE_CNT = 800 pixels = 0x320**
- **DE_LIN = 600 pixels = 0x258**
- **DE_DLY = 216 pixels = 0xD8**
- **DE_TOP = 27 pixels = 0x1B**

Answer (score 1):

Since the video is coming with it's own DE/HS/VS, you must generate the exact same DE from HS and VS to match the active lines and pixels, or the picture is shifted from the center position.

HRES is something you can measure, it is pixel clocks per line.
VRES is something you can measure, it is lines per frame.

Then DE_DLY and DE_TOP are just set to values that center the picture.
In fact you can measure that too, based on original HS/DE and VS/DE relationship.